# Casting/Changing type to pointer to type (SDL_Rect)

Tags: c++, pointers, sdl

I'm trying to pass a `SDL_Rect` to `SDL_RenderCopy`, which takes the adress of a `SDL_Rect`. I've got the `SDL_Rect` I'm trying to pass stored in my private class (called "Shot") variabes in the `Shot.h` file.

This is all happening in `Shot.cpp`

My way of doing it:

```
SDL_RenderCopy(other args..., &Shot::rect)
```

However visual studio complains that

```
"argument of type SDL_Rect Shot::* is incompatible with param of type const SDL_Rect *"
```

I do understand the error a fair bit, but cant quite see how to convert `Shot::rect` to a simple adress...

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] to get help diagnosing your code. You left many things out in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to use `&Shot::rect`, `rect` needs to be a `static member` of the `Shot` class.

To pass a pointer to a `non-static` member, the following can be used:

```
Shot sh;
SDL_RenderCopy(other args..., &sh.rect);
```

Otherwise there would be no way to know which `rect` of which `Shot` object to use.

---

If you want to pass a member of a class to a function, that function will need to know which object of that class it has to use.

So you have to pass the object from which you will use the `rect` as part of the parameter: `&sh.rect` in the above example.

If you use `&Shot::rect`, it is not known which object to use, thus `rect` needs to be static member then. That way there is only one `rect` for all objects of that class.

For example, if there are multiple objects of `class Shot`:

```
Shot sh1;
Shot sh2;
```

The function needs to know which rect to use: `sh1.rect` or `sh2.rect`.

In case `SDL_RenderCopy()` is called from within `class Shot` (or is a member function), `rect` can be passed directly like this:

```
SDL_RenderCopy(other args..., &rect);
```

Comment: Does this really need to be done in the Shot.cpp class which defines functions etc. ?

Comment: @PeterLikesCode - If you want to pass a member of a class to a function, that function will need to know which object of that class to use. So you have to pass the object from which you will use the rect as part of the parameter: `&sh.rect`. If you use `&Shot::rect`, it is not known which object to use, thus rect needs to be static then so there is only one rect for all objects of that class.

Comment: I come from a java background so this is kinda hard for me to understand. How am I supposed to specify which instance of Shot I'm going to use IN the file that I use to define the functions and memebers of shot? Thanks for the help

Comment: @PeterLikesCode - You don't have to know that to define your class, unless of course `SDL_RenderCopy()` is a member function of `class Shot`, or called from within `class Shot` - then you'd only need: `SDL_RenderCopy(other args..., &rect);`.

Comment: I have now understood that I asked incorrectly. I totally misinterpreted classes as a whole. Thanks for the fast responses.

Comment: @PeterLikesCode - No problem - glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get an address of a class variable, unless it's static. I assume you want to create an **object** of class `Shot`, and then get address of it's member. The most elegant way would be to write a proper method for this.

```
class Shot {
protected:
    SDL_Rect rect;
public:
    SDL_Rect const *getRect(void) const { return &rect; }
};
```

Then you can use:

```
Shot *shot = new Shot;
SDL_RenderCopy(other args..., shot->getRect())
```

Comment: How would I go about doing this? I'm using the code I specified in the Shot.cpp class (Where I define functions etc,). How come the compiler not know which shot I'm asking for?

Comment: @PeterLikesCode: I am not sure if I understand you correctly... Class is just a "definition" of an object. You can have many objects and in your SDL_RenderCopy call you have to identify what object you would like to get `rect` from.